# Match on Multiple Rows in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, select

I got a complex SQL Server query I'm trying to knock out, hitting a wall and not sure the best / fastest way.  I got a good start but not getting it all right.

Basically, I need to create a Select statement thats going to me a list of `content_ids` that meet the following requirements:

- Unique `content_id` with `field_id` of 12680 that `field_values` match
- `content_id` with `field_id` of 12643 that don't have 'Yes' but another row with the same `content_id` but `field_id` 12680 matches this same `content_id` with the value of 'Yes'
- Only items with `create_date` in the last 24hrs

The database looks like:

```
content_id | field_id | field_value                             | create_date
_________________________________________________________________________________________
12         | 12680    | 210b1183c3718142594425ab9538376ebb7f1e0 | 2012-02-21 22:44:51.167
12         | 12643    | Yes                                     | 2012-02-21 22:44:51.167
13         | 12680    | 210b1183c3718142594425ab9538376ebb7f1e0 | 2012-02-21 22:44:51.167
13         | 12643    |                                         | 2012-02-21 22:44:51.167
```

Heres what I got so far:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Event1.content_id
FROM tblIVTextData AS Event1
    JOIN tblIVTextData AS Event2
        ON (Event1.content_id != Event2.content_id AND 
            Event1.field_value = Event2.field_value)
    JOIN tblIVTextData AS Event3
        ON(Event3.field_id = 12643 AND
           Event3.field_value = 'Yes' AND
           Event3.content_id = Event1.content_id)
    WHERE Event1.field_id = 12680 AND 
        Event1.create_date > dateadd(hh, -300, getdate())
```

I'm getting lost on selecting the first occurrence of the 'Yes' with field_values matching.  Any suggestions on how to accomplish this or perf improvements?

Comment: Must the `content_id` meet both of the first two criteria or either of them?

Comment: @amcdni . . . This statement does not make sense:  "content_id with field_id of 12643 that don't have 'Yes' but another row with the same content_id but field_id 12680 matches this same content_id with the value of 'Yes'".  Could you provide the output you want for your sample data?

Comment: @GordonLinoff Sample output would look like: 

content_id 
13

Answer (score 3):

I don't understand your conditions, nor the sample query (you say "24" hours as a condition but use "300" hours in the SQL).

However, I think you can do what you want with aggregation and a `having` clause.  Here is an example that tests for one occurrence of 12680 and at least one occurrence of 12643 with `field_value <> 'Yes'`:

```
select e.ContentId
from tblIVTextData e
where e.create_date > dateadd(hh, -24, getdate())
group by e.ContentId
having sum(case when field_id = 12680 then 1 else 0 end) = 1 and
       sum(case when field_id = 12643 and field_value <> 'Yes' then 1 else 0 end) > 0
```

Comment: Whoops ... 300 was a typo

Answer (score 0):

```
with content_cte(content_id,field_id)as
(select distinct content_id,field_id from tblIVTextData where content_id=12643 
and field_value <>'Yes')

SELECT DISTINCT Event1.content_id
FROM 
tblIVTextData AS Event1
JOIN tblIVTextData AS Event2
ON (Event1.content_id != Event2.content_id AND 
Event1.field_value = Event2.field_value)
JOIN content_cte AS Event3
ON(Event3.content_id = Event1.content_id AND Event1.field_value='Yes')
WHERE Event1.field_id = 12680 
Event1.create_date > dateadd(hh, -24, getdate())
```